# d3 chart not rendering with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

Following an example page to try to set up react+d3 and I am seeing a blank page render. The guide is at https://dzone.com/articles/how-you-can-translate-any-random-d3-example-to-rea

Full component code (although it is mainly a copy+paste):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as topojson from 'topojson';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

class CongressionalDistricts extends Component {
    state = {
    usData: null,
    usCongress: null
}

componentWillMount() {
    // load data
    d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Swizec/113th-congressional-districts/master/public/us.json")
        .defer(d3.json, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Swizec/113th-congressional-districts/master/public/us-congress-113.json")
        .await((error, usData, usCongress) => {
            this.setState({
                usData,
                usCongress
            })
        })
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    // render example D3

    const svg = d3.select(this.refs.anchor)
    // const {width, height} = this.props;
    const width = 960;
    const height = 600;


    const projection = d3.geoAlbers()
        .scale(1280)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    // console.log(projection);

    const path = d3.geoPath(projection);
    console.log('path');
    // console.log(path);

    const us = this.state.usData
    const congress = this.state.usCongress;
    console.log(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land));
    console.log(us);
    console.log(congress);

    svg.append("defs").append("path")
        .attr("id", "land")
        .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip-land")
        .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", "#land");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "districts")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-land)")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(congress, congress.objects.districts).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .append("title")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "district-boundaries")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(congress, congress.objects.districts, function (a, b) {
            return a !== b && (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0);
        }))
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "state-boundaries")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function (a, b) {
            return a !== b;
        }))
        .attr("d", path);
}

render() {
    const {usData, usCongress} = this.state;

    if (!usData || !usCongress) {
        return null;
    }

    return <g ref="anchor"/>;
}
}
```

on inspecting the console I see the warning:

> The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a
>   React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

As well as that there is available in a 0x0  element. I've tried hardcoding as well as rendering from within a parent component passing the props but still see now chart. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you miss the closing brace for the CongressionalDistricts component?

Comment: Sorry, I see that the brace landed outside of the code block. The syntax is valid when I open the page as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're not trying to do this in Internet Explorer are you?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I mainly use Chrome but also see the same in Firefox.

Comment: This could be [because](https://github.com/hyperfuse/react-anime/issues/33) you are rendering your `CongressionalDistricts` component outside of an `<svg>` elememt, where a `<g>` doesn't make sense.  Or it could be because React 16 introduced `<Fragment>` which could be used instead?  Does your SVG actually render, despite this "error"?

Comment: What's that `return <g ref="anchor"/>` in your `render`? Maybe it must be `return <svg ref="anchor"/>`?

Comment: @ArashMotamedi `<g>` is an svg group.  Google it.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan updating tthe return statement to:
return <svg ref="anchor" width="900" height="600"/>;
causes the map to render. However passing in the props from another component fails.

Comment: What I also see is I was able to get this to render if I leave it as a g tag in the d3 component and wrap that in an SVG tag which I believe was suggested earlier as well. Thank you!